# Gödel's Incompleteness theorem in modal logic

Tags: logic, incompleteness, modal-logic

I think I once taught that the statement of the Gödel's Incompleteness theorem is equivalent to :

$ \diamond \neg \square \square p $, if p is a complex enough system.

Is this right?

Comment: Side note: since $\Box p\implies \Box\Box p$ for every reasonable theory $T$, what you've written can be simplified to just $\Diamond \neg\Box p$.

Answer (score 3):

This is not right. There's a few things wrong here.

- First, you seem to be using $p$ to denote both a **statement** which is undecidable, and the **theory** (usually denoted "$T$") that we're analyzing. The latter is built into the modalities - e.g. "$\Box p$" means "$T$ proves $p$," etc. (Note that if we want to talk about different theories, we have to use different modalities - this is often a stumbling point.)
- Second, what you've written means "it is consistent that $p$ is not provably provable." This is true if $p$ is undecidable in $T$, but it's not really what we want to say. Godel's first incompleteness theorem says that (for appropriate $T$) if $T$ is consistent, then there is an undecidable sentence - that is, $$\neg\Box \perp\implies [\neg\Box p\wedge\neg\Box\neg p]$$ where "$\perp$" is a name for the sentence $0=1$ (say) and $p$ is the Godel sentence (well, actually $p$ should be the *Rosser* sentence, but whatever). Godel's second incompleteness theorem then says the same thing, but for a different $p$ - namely, "$Con(T)$."

Of course, you might mean different things by your modal operators than I do; but then you should specify what you mean.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it was T, theory, that I wanted to specify. I want to rephrase the statement: "if T is consistent, then there is an undecidable sentence" in handy way. I meant "I cannot think that I am definitely right" by modal operators in my question. If I add "if I am not losing my sanity," will it correspond to Gödel's first incompleteness theorem?

Comment: What texts on modal logic can you recommend for mathematicians?  Especially ones that include the incompleteness theorem.  I've seen the incompleteness theorem but not in any of my modal logic books.